# MS Office 2010 - Last used template directory (VBA)

Tags: templates, ms-word, automation, directory

I have a question about scripting macros for MS Office 2010, more specific for Word.
I am looking for a way to save a document, that was created from a template, right in the directory where the template is saved (Not the standard template directory).

For example you got a directory for letters, where the letter template is saved and a directory for flyers, where the template for flyers is saved. You create a new flyer from the template and want to save it. If it is in many subdirectories it will take too many clicks to get there, so I was looking for a way to automatically get the directory where the template, from what the current file was created, is saved or maybe the last used directory for templates.

I neither used VBA nor any macros for Office and I also did not find any solutions so far.

I would appreciate any thoughts that could help me and others with the same problem.

EDIT:

As Cindy suggested to say how I want to execute the macro, I would like to add, that I want to use the built-in save feature to open a dialog box if the file does not exist yet.

But today I unexpectedly found the answer I was looking for. I am sorry that I created a new question for this, although I found it one day later, but I did not know I would. :P

Anyway, here is the code I found (It is not from me):

```
Sub FileSave()

    If ActiveDocument.Path = "" Then    'If document was never saved yet
        FileSaveAs
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ActiveDocument.Save

End Sub
Sub FileSaveAs()

    Dim DocName As String

    With ActiveDocument
       DocName = "/path
    End With

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Name = DocName
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What you propose is not really very difficult, as far as writing the code goes. But what is not clear is when/how you want the code to execute. For example, do you want a button in the Ribbon (easy for you)? Do you want the Save command to do this automatically, without showing you the dialog box (more difficult)? Do you want the dialog box to suggest that directory when you use the built-in File/Save As? Think that over very carefully, then click EDIT below your question to add that information to your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName() to get the directory name of the template file and use that directory to save your new file.

Comment: Your suggestion is not appropriate for VBA. What you propose is .NET Framework.